# Resource Hacker seems to "break" aero.msstyles in Win7 (?)

Tags: windows-7, themes

I have been trying to change the color of my taskbar with little success. We have two nearly identical machines on a KVM switch and it's easy to forget which one you're on, but they have quite different purposes so I want them both to have very different taskbar colors since that's the one thing that is always visible.

I am trying to modify the .png files in aero.msstyles which I know has worked for some people. But whenever I try it, I restart and then my taskbar turns plain grey and reverts to the old-school START bar instead of the Windows 7 bar with the Windows logo start button.  In other words, it looks like it's skipping the aero theme all together.  The only way to get it back is to replace the aero.msstyles file I modified with the backup of the original I made before starting.

At first I thought maybe the image editor was not saving the .png in a format that could be understood (or possibly adding metadata that was confusing things) but I tried simply extracting any .png file, and then replacing that resource with the same UNEDITED .png file in aero.msstyles -- and this STILL broke the theme, even with .png files that are totally unrelated to the taskbar.

All I'm doing is extracting any .png file using Resource Hacker, then replacing the image with that same .png file, so in theory nothing has changed.  My best guess is the problem is something with Resource Hacker re-saving the file.  Can anyone familiar with this process shed some light on what I might be doing wrong, or a workaround to get me going?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't Windows 7 have a number of built in colour options anyway? Pretty sure mine does.

Comment: I haven't found any that are able to be applied by group policy.  Replacing aero.msstyles via a script on the other hand -- that we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set one to the Classic (AKA Windows 2000) theme? Differences would be pretty obvious then.
I'm not on my 7 machine, but Control Panel / Display / Personalization, I think?

Comment: Thanks, that's not a bad idea, but I have gone forth with a color-coding scheme, adding color coding to logon screens and wallpapers via group policy, so would really prefer to color-code the taskbars as well to match the color coding we have associated with the different tasks these computers are dedicated to.